# performance problem sql server 2005 update sentence

Tags: sql-server

I have a table "OFICIAL3" with 500k rows. and 30 columns. and table INSIS with 150k rows and 20 columns.
OFICIAL3.NUMERO_TITULO has an index.
INSIS.NumeroDocumento has an index too.
update sentence take long time. this process will take 9 hours in my machine
my machine is a core 2 duo 2.GHZ and 2GB RAM

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CompletarDatos] AS
declare @cantidad int;
declare @CONTADOR int;
declare @NRO_TITULO VARCHAR(600);
declare @POYECTO VARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @I_PROYECTO VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @I_AREA_INT VARCHAR(500);

SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

SET @cantidad =(select count(*) from OFICIAL3)
SET @CONTADOR=1

declare CURSORITO cursor for
select NUMERO_TITULO from OFICIAL3
open CURSORITO


 fetch next from CURSORITO
into @NRO_TITULO


 while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin

        SET @CONTADOR=@CONTADOR+1
        PRINT 'ROW='+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30),@CONTADOR)+' NRO TITULO='+@NRO_TITULO

        SET @I_PROYECTO = (SELECT  PROYECTO FROM INSIS WHERE NumeroDocumento=@NRO_TITULO)
        SET @I_AREA_INT = (SELECT  I_AREA_INTERVENCION FROM INSIS WHERE NumeroDocumento=@NRO_TITULO)             

        UPDATE OFICIAL3 SET PROYECT=@I_PROYECTO , COD_AREA=@I_AREA_INT WHERE NUMERO_TITULO=@NRO_TITULO      

        fetch next from CURSORITO   into @NRO_TITULO

end   

 -- cerramos el cursor
  close CURSORITO
  deallocate CURSORITO

END
```

Comment: You really need to find an approach that doesn't involve a cursor. That is likely the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming OFICIAL4 is a typo, this should work as a single update:

```
UPDATE  o
SET     PROYECT = i.PROYECTO,
        COD_AREA = i.I_AREA_INTERVENCION
FROM    OFICIAL3 o
        INNER JOIN
                INSIS i
                ON o.NUMERO_TITULO = i.NumeroDocumento
```

As others have commented, an approach that avoids the CURSOR is vastly preferable from a performance point of view. Another thought is that a covering index on `INSIS (NumeroDocumento, PROYECTO, I_AREA_INTERVENCION) would speed things up further for this query.

Comment: How long time should I wait ?

Comment: Have added a second, more minor suggestion. But avoiding the CURSOR should make a significant difference.

Comment: Thanks I will add index to those fields too. Is there any way to know how much time is left.?

Comment: I mean a single index on the three fields in that order, in case that wasn't clear. No way to tell how much time is left without cursoring and writing messages out as you have done - which will slow things down. How long did it take in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way you can do this without a cursor?  Removing the iteration should help it considerably.

Comment: Yes there is - see my answer a minute before yours... ;)